# How to load values from a select in my GridView?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to load the result of my select in my GridView, but simply not charged anything. I checked all the code.

My making DAL **Select** and saves the type **list <>**

```
 using System;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using MySql.Data;
 using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
 using Geax1.Model;

 namespace Geax1.DAL
{
public class ListaVeiculosDAL
{
    private static List<_Veiculos> lv = new List<_Veiculos>();
    public static void ListaVeiulos(_Clientes obj)
    {
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;Database=xpto;User ID=root;Password='';"))
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tab_veiculo ORDER BY id;", conn);

                DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(dataset);

                foreach (DataRow linha in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    _Veiculos veiculo = new _Veiculos();

                    veiculo.Modelo1 = Convert.ToString(linha["modelo"]);
                    veiculo.Placa1 = Convert.ToString(linha["placa"]);
                    veiculo.Quilometragem1 = Convert.ToString(linha["quilometragem"]);
                    veiculo.Cor1 = Convert.ToString(linha["cor"]);
                    veiculo.Chassi1 = Convert.ToString(linha["chassi"]);
                    veiculo.Quilometragem1 = Convert.ToString(linha["tipo"]);

                    lv.Add(veiculo);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<_Veiculos> retornaVeiculo()
    {
        return lv;
    }
  }
}
```

Calling my method inside my **GridView**. However, when running the page is blank, no value of **select**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Geax1.DAL;
using Geax1.Model;

namespace Geax1.Views
{
 public partial class ListagemVeiculos : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         GrdVeiculo.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
         GrdVeiculo.DataSource = ListaVeiculosDAL.retornaVeiculo();
         GrdVeiculo.DataBind();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling method in which you load data so you always get empty list.You must call `ListaVeiulos` method before `retornaVeiculo` method.

```
     GrdVeiculo.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
     _Clientes obj=new _Clientes();
     ListaVeiculosDAL.ListaVeiulos(obj); 
     GrdVeiculo.DataSource = ListaVeiculosDAL.retornaVeiculo();
     GrdVeiculo.DataBind();
```

Or you can call that method directly in DAL

```
public static List<_Veiculos> retornaVeiculo()
{
    _Clientes obj=new _Clientes();
    ListaVeiulos(obj);
    return lv;
}
```

Comment: Error 1 The name 'obj' does not exist in the current context

Comment: check updated answer. you should pass your _Clientes class object.

Comment: No suitable resource for the specified culture (or the neutral culture) was found in the given assembly. Make sure "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Properties.Resources.resources" was embedded or linked into assembly "MySql.Data.CF" correctly at compile time, or that all necessary satellite assemblies can be loaded and fully signed.